# Do I need to control for time dummies when running VAR?

Tags: vector-autoregression, categorical-encoding

I was reading some articles on running VAR but none of the articles talked about controlling for time dummies. Is this something I need to consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not include a dummy for each time period in your data (as you might sometimes do in models for panel data) as that would result in perfect multicollinearity and prevent identification of the model's parameters. (Unlike panel data, in multivariate time series we are not observing the same variables across two dimensions -- time and individuals -- but different variables across a single dimension -- time. It possible to include time dummies in panel data as there is one remaining dimention -- individuals -- that still varies within each time period, but in multivariate time series this is not the case.)

You may consider including one-off dummies to account for outliers or periodic dummies to account for seasonality.

Comment: Great. Thank you!